# How do i determine whether a particular image has already been cached using angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have a webapp that loads a collection of small images on a particular page. I want to show a load spinner on the spots where an image that has not yet been cached should appear. To check which spots should have a load spinner i want to check whether the file name of the image that should be on a spot is already present in the browser cache. If not then it shows a spinner instead while the image is retrieved by the browser.

I would also like to know if there is a way for angular to know when the browser is done retrieving all the images it didn't cache yet in the past. I would like to be able to subscribe to this event. When its done caching then the app can stop showing the spinner and show the images instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is not going to know about what is cached or not. What you want to do is have an unloaded property that represents unloaded images

```
unloaded: number = 10;
```

And on each image put an unloaded = unloaded -1;

```
<img src="url" (load)="unloaded = unloaded - 1">
```

And show your spinner based on unloaded

```
<spinner *ngIf="unloaded"></spinner>
```

Comment: brilliant idea, i'll try it out tomorrow. If it works for me i will accept this as the answer.